# 30,000 locations on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, location-services

I want to show 30,000 location on google maps using JS. But my Browser is not responsive. Can anyone suggest me some solution. My code is is below :-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .loader {
            border-top: 16px solid blue;
            border-right: 16px solid green;
            border-bottom: 16px solid red;
            border-left: 16px solid pink;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        }
        @keyframes spin {
                0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
                100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/src/jquery.csv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=nsddjfhjshfghjsdfgjhfhjfhvf&callback=initMap" async defer></script>


  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="inputs" class="clearfix">
    <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
  </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
      $(".map").hide();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 28.6139, lng: 77.2090},
          zoom: 5

        });



      }


      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#files').bind('change', handleFileSelect);
    });

       function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
      var file = files[0];

      printTable(file);


    }
    function printTable(file) {

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      var markers = [];

      reader.onload = function(event){
        var csv = event.target.result;
        var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);


        var temp;

        for(var row in data) {

          for(var item in data[row]) {

          temp=data[row][item];

          if (!temp.trim() || temp.trim()  == null || temp.trim() =='') {
            console.error("string empty");  
          }
          else
          {

          //console.log(data[row][item]);  
          var array1 = JSON.parse(data[row][item]); 
          markers.push(array1);

          delete this.array1;
        }         
          }
        }
         showMarker(markers);


       };


    }


    function showMarker(mark)
    {

    for(var array1 in mark) {

            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: mark[array1][1], lng: mark[array1][0]},
                icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 2,
                fillColor: '#F44336',
                strokeColor: '#F44336',
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 0
                },

                map: map,
             });
         }


         $(".map").show();
      }

     </script>



     </body>
     </html>
```

Any Suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Have you considered grouping markers depending on the zoom level, then only displaying the subset that is containsed in the zoomed-in area? Example: https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html

Comment: Pawel I don't want to be grouped i want it to be all the markers to be visible so i can track the density on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe aggregate the points together when zoomed far out? I had a similar problem once with Google Charts. I solved it by determining a max number of points to show at once and aggregating points together to get that value. The view was redrawn on a zoom.